# Is this calculation correct of the directional derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the following:

[image]

and

[image]

What I did:

Calculate the derivatives in each variable in the point (3,2,1)

Calculate the product of the vector (1,2,3) by the derivatives in the point (3,2,1), such that:

$D_{(1,2,3)}f(3,2,1)=yz.1+xz.2+xy.3=2+6+18=26$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the directional derivative of $f(x, y, z)$ at a point $P$ in the direction of a vector $\mathbf v$ is given by $D_{\mathbf v}(f(P)) = \nabla f(P) \cdot \mathbf u,$ where $\mathbf u$ is a unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf v.$ Like you said, $$\nabla f(P) = \langle yz, xz, xy \rangle \big|_{P \, = \, (3, 2, 1)} = \langle 2, 3, 6 \rangle.$$ Unfortunately, we are not lucky enough to have that $\mathbf v = \langle 1, 2, 3 \rangle$ is a unit vector. Particularly, we have that $||\mathbf v|| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4 + 9} = \sqrt{14},$ and we must take $\mathbf u = \frac 1 {||\mathbf v||} \mathbf v$ as our unit vector when we compute the directional derivative. Luckily, the dot product is bilinear, so we have $$D_{\langle 1, 2, 3 \rangle}(f(3, 2, 1)) = \nabla f(3, 2, 1) \cdot \mathbf u = \frac 1 {\sqrt{14}} \nabla f(3, 2, 1) \cdot \langle 1, 2, 3 \rangle = \frac{\langle 2, 3, 6 \rangle \cdot \langle 1, 2, 3 \rangle}{\sqrt{14}} = \frac{26}{\sqrt{14}}.$$